# Python how to use the len() on pig game

Tags: python

so basically when does the len() > 0 come to play

what does it mean if len(original_term) > 0 
                      print....
                    else: what ??? (original != ) is that what it means???
THanK YOU

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#len

Comment: This is very basic question, I think you should find and do some python tutorial. And FAQ on stackexchange, to learn how question should be asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More than likely your code would read (in more "human" terms)if the length of original_term is more than zero characters print something.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a string it checks whether the length of the string is greater than zero. If it is, you `print` something. For lists, it checks whether the number of elements in the list is greater than zero, `print` something.

Basically, it checks if the string/list is not empty and if it is, it executes what follows the  `else` statement.